# Node, when I run package.json `bin` `command` , give me `syntax error near unexpected token `(' `

Tags: node.js

when I run package.json `bin` `command` , give me `syntax error near unexpected token`(' ` .

`package.json`:

```
 "bin": {
    "grabfilenames": "./index.js"
 }
```

`npm link`:

```
/usr/local/bin/grabfilenames -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grabfilename/index.js                                                                                                                                                                               
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grabfilename -> /Users/dulin/workspace/grabfilename
```

when I run my `cli`:

`grabfilenames -p /Users/dulin/workspace/learn-jquery`

give me an error:

```
/usr/local/bin/grabfilenames: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/local/bin/grabfilenames: line 1: `const fs = require('fs');'
```

How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The documentation states that:

> On install, npm will symlink that file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local installs.

This means that npm does **nothing special** to your file and expect it to be executable on unix. Your `bin` file can be a perl script, a compiled C program, a shell script, a Ruby script or even a node.js javascript app.

Therefore what causes your app to run is not npm. It is your OS. So your script **must** be executable (as I said, it can even be a compiled binary).

On unix, to automatically execute a script with the correct interpreter you need to have a [sh-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line in the file. For node.js I generally use this line:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
```

You can generally just use:

```
#! /whatever/path/to/node
```

but depending on the OS or even distro node.js may be installed at different locations. So `/usr/bin/env` is a program that loads your default environment variables which includes `$PATH` that will allow the shell to automatically find where node.js is installed.

Comment: I don't know how this would work on Windows. It should work on bash shell on Windows.